# How can i make a website on tor but also accesible on public adress

Tags: website

i have seeen a lot of services like mail ones on tor that you can access to a page that describes it on the public web, or recieve mails from the public web.

This question is because i need to make a web on tor so anyone knows the owner but also to be accesible from the public web.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In that scenario, the service is not really *hidden*, as it would probably be easy to figure out that the clearnet site and the hidden service are the same. It is accessible through Tor as a .onion address, so people can visit your site anonymously.

You can turn any web server into a hidden service. Or rather: you can point a Tor HS at any web server. You don't even have to host the web server yourself.

Just set up a web site anywhere. Then run a Tor with a HiddenServicePort that points to your web site. Your Tor may run on the same host as your web server but it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

To setup a Tor hidden service, you're allowing a certain port (your web service) to be accessible via the Tor network. In the same way that you can provide a port to the Internet.

Choose your web server of choice, set it up to be public on the Internet, then also run a Tor hidden service on the same machine and point it the same port that you're running the web server on. There shouldn't be anything special about it.